# CAAnimation & Multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, caanimation

I have a root View Controller (VC) that manages two other VC and for portrait and one for landscape and within each of these there's a number of other VC's. One of the lower level VC's has an animation method that is trigger by a notification from the root VC.

This is working and the animation starts but is hidden/obscured when it moves outside of the VC's frame. So my questions are as follows:

- Is CAAnimation restricted to within the VC that initiates the animation?
- Is it possible to create an animation that moves across multiple VC's, if it is are there any examples that may help?

If you can imagine my root VC contains four VC's one in each corner, I'm trying to animate a view that is in the bottom left corner so that it travels up to the top right of the screen. The animation method is initiated from the bottom left hand corner VC.

Comment: In general i think it customary to use one view controller to handle multiple orientations of the same view... that view either has 2 layouts or gets swapped for a portrait/landscape view.

Comment: I would imagine the `masksToBounds` property is what you're after.